# TestNG fails to shutdown Selenium Browser in AfterClass method

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, testng

The scenario is this:
TestNG test runner that runs my Cucumber features. 
There's a static shared Selenium WebDriver pool that contains WebBrowsers.
At the end of the TestNG testing I want to shut down my browsers so I'm using an @AfterClass annotation. 
The call is made, and the code runs to shut down the browsers, however they never actually do.

If I add a Thread.sleep for a second after the call is made, the browser shuts down fine.

The JUnit test runner manages to close the browser down without fail each time. Whats so special (wrong) about TestNG?

---

Link to offending test runner is here:

https://github.com/OliverCulleyDeLange/Cucumber_Selenium_Hamcrest/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/oliverdelange/testrunners/testng/TestNGCucumberRunner.java

Feel free to clone and see results for yourself.

---

Code for Offending test runner:

```
package uk.co.oliverdelange.testrunners.testng;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import uk.co.oliverdelange.webbrowser.BrowserPool;

@CucumberOptions(tags = "~@Ignore",
        features = "src/test/resources/uk/co/oliverdelange/cucumber/",
        glue = "uk.co.oliverdelange.cucumber.tests",
        format = {"pretty","html:CucumberReports/html/","json:CucumberReports/cucumber.json"},
        monochrome = true
)
public class TestNGCucumberRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("Do stuff here before the cucumber tests happen");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() { //FIXME why is this not being called?
        System.out.println("Do stuff here after the cucumber tests happen");
        System.out.println("Like shutting down all the web browsers...");
        BrowserPool.closeAll();
        //FIXME: JUnit manages to close the browser before closing the tests, but somehow TestNG doesn't - what!?
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that a lot of people like TestNG, but by my experience, it is full of bugs and they are rarely fixed. I had an issue with the life cycle annotations myself quite a while ago (https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/425) and even proposed a patch that was never merged. I can unfortunately only recommend not to use TestNG. JUnit has a much cleaner code base while TestNG is a mess full of errors. I would not wonder if you stumbled upon such a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen someone do a call to close a group/pool of webdriver instances in a single call in a AfterClass method.   Normally, what people do is instantiate the browser in BeforeTest and then close the single non-static class webdriver member with a .quit call in the AfterTest method.  So, my first impression, looking at your code, is you are doing something non-standard and experimental.   TestNG is awesome, it forks processes for you and its easy to keep track of webdriver instances in that case.  I wouldn't use JUnit ever... after I got to know TestNG , I am convinced it is far superior.

For example:

> 1. You can pass an optional Object[] arg to a method annotated with BeforeMethod and from that you can retrieve the arguments that are
>      about to be passed to the test method, such as a WebDriver helper object (generated within a data provider method) that opens a browser once you call obj.start . Genius.
> 2. You can pass ITestResult to a AfterTest method and then get stuff from the result and post process stuff with that information, such as
>      sending a SauceLabs REST request after your test is done to mark a test job as passed.

Comment: But that required opening a new browser per test which is dog slow. This way we have a pool of browsers that the tests can tap into which are opened when needed.
Completely agree its non standard and experimental :D

Comment: Yes, it opens one browser thread per test but, for example, this is how Selenium Grid works, and so yes, it is a standard to open a new browser for each individual test.  If you want to work with a homegrown browser pool, then you are ruling yourself out of using Selenium Grid, which is also very non-standard.   Selenium Grid IS a browser pool and you are re-inventing the wheel.  If I were you, I would stop worrying about a little slowness starting browsers and focus more on what you get out of your tests.

Comment: I'm not doing this for any particular project or requirement, just to try and improve the current process and speed things up. I tried this on my work Ubuntu machine and it works fine without the Thread.sleep. So i'm even more confused now. Possibly some weird edge case / environment issue. Cheers anyway!